# ERROR invalid OAuth credentials when trying to use `conjure-up kubernetes`

Tags: conjure-up, single-sign-on

Following [Local Kubernetes development with LXD guideline](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/local/), I'm stuck with conjure-up.
I selected `kubernetes core` and now I'm supposed to authenticate with Ubuntu SSO.
I'm using the same credentials which allow me to authenticate successfully on launchpad.net - what can be wrong?
I'm getting `ERROR invalid OAuth credentials`.

Comment: Are you using jaas?

Comment: Yes, I'm using jaas

Comment: That's odd b/c local installations don't require jaas just LXD. So this question is confusing.

Comment: It's odd indeed